# Can I do CRUD operations with Couchbase Lite through CouchbaseClient

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-lite

We are currently using Couchbase in a product (not released) but we are thinking of using Couchbase Lite in our test environment. However can we use com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient to do CRUD operations on Couchbase Lite?

I have googled it and read Couchbase Lite doc but I can not get any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have the same interface as Couchbase server. It is intended to work on mobile platforms (IOS/Android) and you don't run the Couchbase server SDK's on those devices. Couchbase Lite isn't a substitute for Couchbase server.

However, that being said, we do have a Go lang based "lite" version of Couchbase server called cbgb that you can use. It's not as scalable as Couchbase server (doesn't cluster or scale horizontally), but is definitely usable for a lot of circumstances: http://cbgb.io/ to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @scalable3 mentioned, for Couchbase Lite's GA we're working on a solution that should allow you to use Couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway alongside your existing Couchbase Server buckets.